# Relaunching an already launched application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, symlink, nsapplication

I have created an application for Mac OS X, and I have a desktop shortcut for it (created using `ln -s`). Now I want to add a feature such that whenever this shortcut is double clicked, with the application already running, some action should be performed (like opening a Finder window at a designated path). How can this be implemented?

I tried to create an observer for `NSApplication`-based notifications inside my application, but nothing constructive came of it.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your application's delegate, implement [`-applicationShouldHandleReopen:hasVisibleWindows:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSApplicationDelegate/applicationShouldHandleReopen%3ahasVisibleWindows%3a) and do whatever you like.